# Adb2c sign in - show recaptcha after 3 failed attempts

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I have successfully implemented recatpcha in our custom policy sign up.  I was wondering if theres a way to enforce it in our sign in policy where if the user fails to authenticate 3 times it will show the recaptha and user wont be able able to try again until recaptcha is successfull.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Sdiego, Were you able to get this working. if so, How did you handled it? it would be a great help if you provide some insights into it.

Comment: Hi @Sdiego, i also want to show recaptcha after 3 failed attempts.
can you tell me how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on few of the below reference and a try from my end.

Either be a sign up and sign in or a just sign up or user flow. Either way, the CAPTCHA will only be shown during sign up.

Reference Link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha#create-a-user-flow